# The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

> Another Exception maybe from the same error - The changes to the
>   database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while
>   updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an
>   inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Saving or accepting
>   changes failed because more than one entity of type
>   'ClientDataStore.Logger.DB.Core.AuditLog' have the same primary key
>   value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique.
>   Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly
>   in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity
>   Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the
>   'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption"" fluent API or
>   'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.;
>   The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot
>   be modified

I have an Asp.Net WebAPI application, which is working with entity framework Code First model, and i'm logging every single request. For that purpose a have a class that inherits DelegatingHandler.
I have overwritten SendAsync method like that.

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        // Get data from token
        IPrincipal _currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User;
        // Start watch to count Milliseconds of execution of request.
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Stop watch after request is complete
        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;            

        try
        {
            bool isRestLoggerEnabled = bool.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestLoggerEnabled"]);
            if (isRestLoggerEnabled && request.Headers.Authorization != null)
            {
                var requestBody = string.Empty;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
                {
                    reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                AuditLog al = new AuditLog();
                al.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                al.HTTPMethod = request.Method.Method;
                al.RequestData = requestBody;
                al.ResponseData = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
                al.DurationMS = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(elapsedMs);
                al.HTTPResponseCode = ((int)result.StatusCode).ToString();
                al.RequestHeaders = request.Headers.ToString();
                al.RequestURL = request.RequestUri.ToString();
                if ((int)result.StatusCode != (int)HttpResponseStatusCodeTypes.Unauthorized)
                {
                    al.UserId = ((_currentUser.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("UserId") != null ? long.Parse((_currentUser.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("UserId").Value) : 0);
                    al.UserPartyId = ((_currentUser.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("UserPartyId") != null ? long.Parse((_currentUser.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("UserPartyId").Value) : 0);
                    al.PlatformId = ((_currentUser.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("PlatformId") != null ? long.Parse((_currentUser.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("PlatformId").Value) : 0);
                    al.ProductId = ((_currentUser.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("ProductId") != null ? long.Parse((_currentUser.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("ProductId").Value) : 0);
                }
                unitOfWork.LoggerRepository<AuditLog>().Add(al);
                unitOfWork.Save();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            loggerManager.Critical(ex, "AuditLogger exception");
        }

        // Log responce and request + time and other 
        if (result.Content != null)
        {
            // once response body is ready, log it
            var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Trace.WriteLine(responseBody);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is the model of the table.

```
public class AuditLog : LoggerEntityBase
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    //[Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string RequestData { get; set; }

    public string ResponseData { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string HTTPResponseCode { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public long UserPartyId { get; set; }

    public long PlatformId { get; set; }

    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2000)]
    public string RequestURL { get; set; }

    public string HTTPMethod { get; set; }

    public string RequestHeaders { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan DurationMS { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm using also unitOfWork and Repository patterns for the database.
In the moment the application is getting a lot of requests, maybe 1000 per 10-15 min) and in some time i'm getting these exceptions, not on every request but they are constantly hitting in every 5-10 minuets or something like that.
One of the things, that is on my mind, that maybe causing the problem is - every record that logger is saving has a lot of data (like 7k-10k chars). And if the application receives  many requests at once and every request is with so much data it can not make it so fast with the db recording and is starting to mess up it's PK id-s. The PK is standard sql generated big int.

Does anyone have any other ideas on what might be going on here?